# Let's make some ads for our site!

Tags: discussion

The members of Programming Puzzles and Code Golf have made a few Community Promotion Ads in order to promote themselves on other sites:

[image][image][image]

*Note: this may or may not be blatant self-promotion <sub>come visit our site we want more users</sub> or subliminal messaging.*

A few other sites have them too, such as [Robotics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpWDJ.gif).

Why don't we make a few of our own? There are several reasons why this would be beneficial:

1. It would bring in more users, obviously. More users is (almost) never a bad thing, especially when they're being referred from other Stack Exchange sites, giving them a high likelihood of already being knowledgeable about our network and rules.
2. By posting them on sites such as Unix & Linux or Super User, we can let the users over there know that we exist! Many of the users there who know a lot about Vim might not even know that there's now a Vim site at all.
3. Finally, by attracting more users (many of whom may be Vim experts), we'd be addressing one of the major problems that Stack Exchange staff had with there being a Vim site, summed up by @Shog9 in [his recent meta post](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1201/88):

   > Right now, Stack Overflow is still a better place for programmers with vi/Vim questions, Unix & Linux is still a better place for *nix power users with vi/Vim questions, and Super User is still a better place for pretty much everyone else.

   Let's prove him wrong (again)!

So, make an ad and post an answer below! Here are the rules you must follow for the ad:

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (i.stack.imgur.com)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

It should also have a border.

Feel free to make site-specific ads, which can be posted on specific sites (for example, a sysadmin-themed ad tailored specifically for Server Fault).

Comment: why did you choose that dimensions for the picture?

Comment: @guido I think those are determined by SE?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yep, ok makes sense thx

Comment: I don't have time/skills to make *good looking* images, but some idea's people can use: "^C^C^C^Q^Q^ ESC ESC ESC ^Cddsfu; don't how how to quit vi? Try vi.SE" ... " or "Is the only mode you know in vi confusion mode? Try vi.SE" ... Or perhaps  [something inspired by this](http://www.vim.org/images/vimassistant.gif),

Comment: The border is not necessary at all. What it should have is a padding, that is, the text should start some 10px from the boundary.

Comment: Don't commit to posting a specific picture. Different ads might be more appropriate on different sites (e.g. an ad targeted for programmers on [so] and one targeted for sysadmins on [sf]).

Comment: @Gilles Alright, that makes sense. Edited the question.

Answer (score 19):

> Disclaimer : I am not a graphist professional, just a guy playing with photoshop and illustrator

Here is an idea :

- A simple ascii vim logo, I didn't found any existing version of it yet, so I though it could be a possibility. The font is [monaco](https://github.com/cstrap/monaco-font) and the colors are from the [solarized theme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).

  [image]

There are (currently) 4 more, you can find them on a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nobe4/Vim-Ads) I made for the occasion. If you think another one need to be on an answer, so we can vote one, leave a comment and I'll add it.

Also leave a comment here or an issue on the repo if you see improvements / want me to try some of your ideas :)

Comment: These look awesome! Nice work :)

Comment: Beautiful! `vim +ask`, maybe?

Comment: Posted the first one at [ubuntu.se]: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14443/158442 (and it's live now)

Comment: The first one is really great! Good job!

Comment: You should really post 2 separate answers, one for for each ad. That way people can vote for a specific ad. I like the first one, but don't really like the second one (sorry), so should I upvote or not?

Comment: Posted second one on [unix.se]: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3666/70524.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker : I understand what you mean and yes many people don't like the second one because there is a weapon on it, I'll remove it, and leave only the first one.

Comment: Seems to be the wrong size and aspect ratio - 282x320 is `0.88125:1` instead of 220x250's `0.88:1`.

Comment: Yeah, the illustrator export is larger than the required size, I'll update the version with a resized version. Thanks for noticing

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, can you update them to a 300×250 size?

Answer (score 18):

[image]

Comment: Is this a photo of a real terminal or did you [doctor it](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/040/7/7/doctor_who_moon_landing_by_cpd_91-d395n2j.jpg)?

Comment: it is an awesome terminal emulator called CoolRetroTerm: https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term you _want_ to try it (`vi` is an alias for `cat` and .emacs contents were created via figlet; the `nobs` user is hardcoded in the `PS1`)

Comment: Ah, how disappointing :-) For a moment I thought you had gotten a real terminal from your basement (I wish I hadn't thrown away mine now) ... But cool software, certainly fooled me :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker what tells you i don't have a bunch in my carbox, and what tells you i am not too lazy to get off the couch to get there? (it's 10.30pm here)

Comment: Having  a shot of http://vi65.sourceforge.net/ running on a real machine would be great too...

Comment: Why are you editing `~/.emacs`?

Comment: @200_success it's a joke that has been around for quite some time, as a hellish blasphemy against the church of emacs

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Not terribly happy with the text at the bottom, feel free to improve it :)

Comment: Nice. Looks like one for [su]. Though the font kerning for the caption is weird.

Comment: Hilarious!  Kind of sad, though, that our favorite editor is defined by how you *exit* it. ;)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, can you update it to a 300×250 size?